# Cannot convert the value of type ' ' to ' '

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am trying to pull data from an API that I have created. All seemed to be going okay until I started to parse/decode data.

These are the errors that are showing up:

[image: Photo of code with errors]

and this is the code I have

```
import Foundation
struct VaccineManager {
    
    let vaccineURL = "https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/api/v1/data?filters=areaType=overview&structure=%7B%22areaType%22:%22areaType%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22areaCode%22:%22areaCode%22,%22date%22:%22date%22,%22newPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22:%22newPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22,%22newPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByPublishDate%22:%22newPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByPublishDate%22,%22cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22:%22cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate%22,%22cumPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByPublishDate%22:%22cumPeopleVaccinatedSecondDoseByPublishDate%22%7D&format=json"
    
    func performRequest(vaccineURL: String){
        if let url = URL(string: vaccineURL) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                
                if let safeData = data {
                    parseJASON(vaccineData: safeData)
                    
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            
            
        }
    }
    
    func parseJASON(vaccineData: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
       let decodedData =  try decoder.decode(VaccineData.self, from: vaccineData)
            print(decodedData.data[0].date)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

In case this is something to do with it, I also have a file with this code

```
struct VaccineData: Decodable {
    let data: Data
}

struct Data: Decodable {
    let newPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByPublishDate: Int
}
```

Been stuck for days so thank you for your help!

Comment: You have redefined Swift's `Data` type with your own - don't do that. Rename your `Data` to something else, or nest it inside `VaccineData`, if it's only used there

Comment: I am sure you are 100% right, but I don't understand what I need to do.

Comment: Like I said, rename your `Data` type (the one you have at the bottom of your question) to something else.